# Cannot find connection string for connection name 'ApplicationServerWorkflowInstanceStoreConnectionString' (machine config))

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, workflow-foundation-4, machine.config

I registered a connection string named 'ApplicationServerWorkflowInstanceStoreConnectionString in machine config (both the 32bit and 64bit version of machine config). However, the application cannot sees it even though the IIS Manager sees it (in section connection string on particular Web Application). What am I doing wrong?

[image: IIS manager and fail page]

Angelique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you registered the connectionstring to right machine config. Make sure the application pool .NET framework version matches the version of machine config. There are separate machine config files for .NET FW 2 and .NET FW 4..

Comment: I was having a similar problem, and it took me an hour to realize I'd put the values in the machine.config for the right Framework version, but not the right _bitness_ version: I'm running Win7 64-bit, but the app pool was 32-bit, so I needed to update the 32-bit and 64-bit machine.configs. (The OP mentioned this of course but it flew right by me for a long time, so I'm just trying to highlight it here.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget there is a v4 config in

---

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

AND

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config